# Handling request simltaneously in nodejs and passing it's response using only one res.send

Tags: node.js, http

I am developing an API which takes input in XML containing IDs for media and gives output in XMLform with details of given IDs.  I am facing a problem while sending the response of second simultaneous request; here the second request goes into loop showing "loading" on postman.

What I am doing is calling a function in `app.post` which parses the media and gives output in the callback and send it using `res.send`, but it works only for single request.

While doing parallel request to same API either it goes in loop or it gives can't set the headers after they are sent as I am using `res.send` but `res.send` is the only way which I can use to send the response (even the next doesn't work).

```
var getCompositeData =  function(req, res, next){
  abc.getData(req.body, function(err, xmlOutput){
  if(err){
    console.log("error");
  } else {
    xmlData = xmlOutput
    return next()
  }
}

app.post(apiUrl, [
  rawBodyParser({
    type: 'application/xml'
  }),
  app.oauth.authorise()
], getCompositeData, function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  res.send(xmlData);
});
```

Comment: At least share _some_ code, otherwise we have no idea how to help you.

Comment: Where abc.getData is a function in another nodejs file which is parses the data and gives the xml output back to the app.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

```
if (err) {
  console.log("error");
}
```

If an error occurs, you still need to make sure a response will be sent back, otherwise the request will stall until a timeout happens. You can pass an error to `next`, and Express will handle it:

```
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}
```

Next problem:

```
xmlData = xmlOutput
```

`xmlData` is an undeclared variable, which gets overwritten with each request. If two requests happens at (almost) the same time, it's likely that one client gets back an incorrect response (remember, Node.js runs JS code in a single thread; there is not thread-local storage so `xmlData` gets shared between all requests).

A good place to "store" this sort of data is in [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals):

```
res.locals.xmlData = xmlOutput;
return next();

// and later:
res.send(res.locals.xmlData);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the new approach to save the data but my probem still exists. res.send doesn't work for parallel request but not giving any error also.Trying to explore the handling parallel request.

Comment: Perhaps you should share `abc.getData()` then.

Comment: Hey thank you for all your help,the npm express-queue solved my problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-queue the problem was I had some async calls in my abc.getData().  :-)

Comment: Simultaneous async calls is not a problem for Node (in fact, it's its number one feature). Using a queue probably just hides the real issue, and you're likely going to severly limit the performance of your app with it.

Comment: Yes I observed that, Is there any other approach by which I can process such requetsts simultaneously without blocking any other request.Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @Priyanka by writing correct code :) I think there's an issue in `abc.getData()` that is causing your problems, but you'd have to share its implementation if you want help sorting it out.